# CSS underline on hover (and remain when active)

Tags: css

I have written some css to achieve a transitional underline on hover. This works fine, but I cannot find a way to keep the item underlined once it has been clicked.

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0F9CD8;
    display: block; 
    transition: width .3s;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s;
    -moz-transition: width .3s;
    -ms-transition: width .3s;
    -o-transition: width .3s;   
    width: 0;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .3s;
}
```

Comment: You should probably look at the [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) and [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) psudo-classes.

Comment: Whenever you click, add a class to it, something like `active`, that has the same properties as `.nav-link:hover`

Comment: I have tried this - but no luck:

.navbar-nav .nav-link::after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0F9CD8;
    display: block; 
    transition: width .3s;
   -webkit-transition: width .3s;
    -moz-transition: width .3s;
    -ms-transition: width .3s;
    -o-transition: width .3s; 
    width: 0;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .3s;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link a:visited {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0F9CD8;
    display: block;
   width: 100%;
}

Comment: No browser has needed those vendor prefixes in many years and they should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using javascript by using click event listner, inject class in html tag(your link tag) when you click on link new css class will get injected and you can style link using injected css class
write css for underline

```
    .underline-class{ border-bottom: 3px solid #0F9CD8; }
```

javascript:

```
var navLink= document.getElementById("nav-link");

navLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navLink.classList.add("underline-class");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to JS version but the under-line class is not retained when an item is clicked (tested in Plunker).

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 3</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var navLink= document.getElementById("nav-link");

navLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navLink.classList.add("underline-class");
});
```

CSS

```
.nav-link::after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0F9CD8;
    display: block; 
    transition: width .3s;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s;
    -moz-transition: width .3s;
    -ms-transition: width .3s;
    -o-transition: width .3s;   
    width: 0;
}
.nav-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .3s;
}
.underline-class { 
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0F9CD8; 
}
```

Comment: Your JS is trying to get _an_ element with the _ID_ `nav-link`, when it should be getting _all_ elements with the _class_ `nav-link`.

Comment: Sorted. I used the existing class (current-menu-item) and now working. Thanks for all your help.